# Hadoop with docker to run "hdfs dfs -put" error

Tags: docker, hadoop, hdfs

I have a docker image for hadoop. (in my case it is https://github.com/kiwenlau/hadoop-cluster-docker)
I do the job step by step according to this blog. And I can run the docker and Hadoop successfully. However, when I try to put some file in **host machine** to test the **WordCount** test in Hadoop. When I run

```
root@hadoop-master:~# hdfs dfs -put /home/ke/code /input
```

It return an error:

```
put: `/home/ke/code': No such file or directory
```

But this directory actually exists because I can use `cd /home/ke/code` to go to this directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to realize is that the Hadoop instance is running in an environment that is entirely different from the host environment. So the second you run the `sudo ./start-container.sh` command which is mentioned in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kiwenlau/hadoop-cluster-docker) that you're following, you're ideally creating a new subsystem which is independent of your host Operating System ( that contains files under `/home/ke/code` ). Unfortunately in this case the Hadoop Disk File System ( HDFS ) is running inside the newly created subsystem ( known as Docker Container ) and the files you wish to transfer are present elsewhere ( in the host OS).

There is however a fix that you might be able to do to make it work out.

- Edit the `start-container.sh` in this way : Edit the lines **10-16** responsible for starting the hadoop master container to this :-

  ```
  sudo docker run -itd \
          -v /home/ke/:/mnt/ke/ \
          --net=hadoop \
          -p 50070:50070 \
          -p 8088:8088 \
          --name hadoop-master \
          --hostname hadoop-master \
          kiwenlau/hadoop:1.0 &> /dev/null
  ```

The main difference to note here is the `-v` switch which mounts the `/home/ke/` volume from your host system to the Docker container in `/mnt/ke/`.

- Delete the old master container which you've created using the command `docker rm hadoop-master` as well as the slave containers named `hadoop-slave1` upto `hadoop-slave3` using the same `docker rm` command.
- Once this is done run from step 4 onwards as mentioned in GitHub. The command to copy the files would now effectively become   `hdfs dfs -put /mnt/ke/code /input`

Comment: Thanks! But a '\' should be add to the end of the newest command that is "-v /home/ke/:/mnt/ke/ \" . And I also have a question , each time I want to put some files from host machine to the HDFS,  I have the edit the 'start-container.sh', which is sophisticated. Are there any other ways to make HDFS have access to the Host environment？

Comment: You don't have to keep editing the `start-container.sh` file. What you can do is create some temp directory in the host system and mount this directory to the container. This single directory can serve the single purpose to make transfers between any files you want to HDFS and can be achieved by just moving the required files to be copied to this directory

Comment: Once you run the `start-comtainer.sh` script, you actually enter the prompt of the master container. To exit this just run the `exit` command which takes you to the host level prompt. Stop the master and slave containers using the command `docker stop <container-name>` and start them with the `docker start` command in the same way. To enter the prompt of a running master container use the command `sudo docker exec -it hadoop-master bash`.

Comment: It's better in your case if you learn a little more about how to handle Docker containers in general since you're making use of containers for running jobs in Hadoop.

Comment: And to answer the question you posed, there unfortunately is no way to access the host filesystem from the container filesystem without mounting, hence the HDFS in the container cannot have access to the host environment except through the mount directories that you set up.

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer! It helps me a lot!

Comment: No problem. I've faced the same problem elsewhere.